# Why do we create user keywords in robot framework?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, robotframework

At what instances it becomes necessary to define user keywords? Is it necessary to create custom library in order to create user keywords.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of keywords is what gives robot framework its power. It was designed for acceptance test driven development. Acceptance tests are typically written in the language of the user, and often written by a product owner or qa professional in the early stages of development.

If you don't write your own custom keywords, an acceptance test for a login page that leads to a dashboard might would have to look something like this:

```
| | open browser | http://www.example.com | chrome
| | go to | http://www.example.com/login
| | input string | xpath=//form/input[@name='username'] | ${username}
| | input string | xpath=//form/input[@name='password'] | ${password}
| | submit form
| | wait until page contains element | xpath=//div[@id='dashboard_frame']
| | page should contain | welcome to Example.com!
```

The above test is tightly coupled to the implementation and will have to change if the implementation of the page changes. This type of test is difficult for a customer or product owner to read -- they won't care what the elements are named, or really even what is required to log in. Their only concern is whether there are sufficient tests to cover the behavior of the new feature.

By using custom keywords, either written as robot keywords or perhaps implemented as page objects, the test could look like this:

```
| | Go to the login page
| | Log in with valid credentials
| | Verify we are on the dashboard page
```

This example better expresses the intent of the test, regardless of how it is implemented. This tests a *feature* not an *implementation*. This is the type of test that a product owner or customer can easily read to verify that proper tests are being performed.

Combined with the use of page objects, this becomes a very powerful mechanism. Your product owners and test professionals can focus on the features to be tested without having to concern themselves with the implementation.

The implementation details can go in page object definitions that can live in the same code repository as the implementation of the pages themselves. When a developer changes a page, they can change the implementation of the keyword to match, without having to change any of the actual test cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's somehow time-reserving and more efficient to create user defined keywords in the following two cases I would say:

1. Call a keyword more than once (like in a loop or something) maybe
   also with different input variables every time.
2. Organize your test to be easy human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

You use your own keywords for accomplishing tasks which are not possible with the normal set of keywords. You could programm them in Python. Also you can combinate existing keywords in your custom keyword to do a much more difficult task.

You don't need a custom library. Just put your keywords behind the `*** Keywords ***` line.